# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') when trying to console.log the value of the html input tag when btn click

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a make `addEventListener` function to a button, when click it should print the value of the input.

but I'm getting an error message:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

```js
let plus = document.getElementById('btnPlus');
let minus = document.getElementById('btnMinus');
let multiplay = document.getElementById('btnMultiplay');
let divide = document.getElementById('btnDivide');

let inputOne = document.getElementById('firstNum');
let inputTwo = document.getElementById('secondNum');

// if + button click display in result inputOne + inputTwo
plus.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let valueOne = inputOne.value;
  let valueTwo = inputTwo.value;
  console.log(valueOne);


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calcultaor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainHeader">
    <h1> Calculator </h1>
    <label for="">Enter First Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="firstNum"> <br/>
    <label for="">Enter Second Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="secondNum"><br/>
    <button class="btnPlus">+</button>
    <button class="btnMinus">-</button>
    <button class="btnMultiplay">*</button>
    <button class="btnDivide">/</button>
    <h2> The Result Is <span class=span_result /> </h2>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: because there is no button that has id = 'btnPlus'

Comment: You don't have an element with `id` `btnPlus`. You only have an element that has a `class` with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Because this code does not contain an `id`

```html
<button class="btnPlus">+</button>
```

If you want get an element by `id`, the element must contain the `id`.

Try this

```html
<button id="btnPlus">+</button>
```

Comment: Could add a test to show that the element can be found now - by id: `let plus = document.getElementById('btnPlus'); console.log(plus);`

Answer (score 0):

getElementById works only with ID not with classes. Review your HTML

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but this answer has already been given.

Comment: Sorry!!! goldman

Answer (score 0):

The **addEventListener()** method attaches an event handler to an element.

You don't have an element with id btnPlus.

Now the below code is running fine.

You have to define the variable as a Number.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainHeader">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
      <label for="">Enter First Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstNum" /> <br />
      <label for="">Enter Second Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="secondNum" /><br />
      <button id="btnPlus">+</button>
      <button id="btnMinus">-</button>
      <button id="btnMultiplay">*</button>
      <button id="btnDivide">/</button>
      <h2>The Result Is <span id="span_result" /></h2>
    </div>

    <p id="demo">
      <script>
        let plus = document.getElementById("btnPlus");
        let minus = document.getElementById("btnMinus");
        let multiplay = document.getElementById("btnMultiplay");
        let divide = document.getElementById("btnDivide");

        let inputOne = document.getElementById("firstNum");
        let inputTwo = document.getElementById("secondNum");

        const element = plus;
        element.addEventListener("click", function(){
            let valueOne = inputOne.value;
          let valueTwo = inputTwo.value;
          let sum = Number(valueOne)+ Number(valueTwo)
          console.log(sum);
          document.getElementById("span_result").innerHTML =sum
        });

        const element2 = minus;
        element2.addEventListener("click", function(){
            let valueOne = inputOne.value;
          let valueTwo = inputTwo.value;
          let sum = Number(valueOne)- Number(valueTwo)
          console.log(sum);
          document.getElementById("span_result").innerHTML =sum
        });

        const element3 = multiplay;
        element3.addEventListener("click", function(){
            let valueOne = inputOne.value;
          let valueTwo = inputTwo.value;
          let sum = Number(valueOne)* Number(valueTwo)
          console.log(sum);
          document.getElementById("span_result").innerHTML =sum
        });

        const element4 = divide;
        element4.addEventListener("click", function(){
            let valueOne = inputOne.value;
          let valueTwo = inputTwo.value;
          let sum = Number(valueOne)/ Number(valueTwo)
          console.log(sum);
          document.getElementById("span_result").innerHTML =sum
        });

      </script>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```